# NSDateFormatter Puzzle! Is this is new Mountain Lion Bug?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdateformatter

I believe I might have found a bug in `NSDateFormatter`, and I am not sure if this is localized to having a Brazil time zone specified in System Preferences.

A full project is here: http://www.idanfe.com/dl/nsDateFormatterPuzzle.zip

The relevant excerpts of the code is shown below:

```
NSArray *unformattedDatesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2011-09-18",
     @"2011-10-16",@"2011-11-13",@"2011-12-11",@"2012-01-08",@"2012-02-05", nil];

NSString *resultedString = @"";
int ii = 0;
NSUInteger items = [unformattedDatesArray count];
for (ii=0; ii<items; ii++) {
    NSLog(@"original item # %d = %@",ii,[unformattedDatesArray objectAtIndex:ii]);
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:@"original item # "];
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d = ",ii]];
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:[unformattedDatesArray objectAtIndex:ii]];
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n"]];
}
NSDateFormatter *originalFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[originalFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // hh:mm:ss
NSDateFormatter *newFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[newFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // hh:mm:ss
NSString *formattedDate;
for (ii=0; ii<items; ii++) {
    formattedDate = [newFormat stringFromDate:[originalFormat
                                               dateFromString:[unformattedDatesArray objectAtIndex:ii]]];
    NSLog(@"formatted item # %d = %@",ii,formattedDate);
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:@"formatted item # "];
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d = ",ii]];
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:(formattedDate == nil ? @"ERROR" : formattedDate)];
    resultedString = [resultedString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n"]];
}
[resultingStringTextView insertText:resultedString];
```

Basically, I'm starting with an array of 5 `NSString`s which represent dates. I'm creating 2 `NSDateFormatter`s: `originalFormat` is used to convert the original string representation of the date into an actual `NSDate`; `newFormat` is used to create a new desired string representation of the `NSDate` generated with the `originalFormat` date formatter.

This is my resulting log:

```
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] original item # 0 = 2011-09-18
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] original item # 1 = 2011-10-16
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] original item # 2 = 2011-11-13
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] original item # 3 = 2011-12-11
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] original item # 4 = 2012-01-08
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] original item # 5 = 2012-02-05
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] formatted item # 0 = 18/09/2011
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] formatted item # 1 = (null)
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] formatted item # 2 = 13/11/2011
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] formatted item # 3 = 11/12/2011
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] formatted item # 4 = 08/01/2012
2012-08-26 nsDateFormatterPuzzle[3261:303] formatted item # 5 = 05/02/2012
```

Note that if you go to System Preferences --> Date and Time --> Time Zone

and change your Time Zone to Rio de Janeiro, you will have the same results.

================================ TRYING to Workaround ===================================

I am trying to get a workaround this bug meanwhile Apple does not fix it.

I have two problems, one is to render a PDF file from this date, and I think I have solved this by:

```
 if (formated_issue_date == NULL) {
            formated_issue_date = [BHDateFormatter bhDateFormat:data_emissao];

}
```

Using this handler:

```
+(NSString*)bhDateFormat:(NSString *)inputedDate{

    NSString *formattedDate = @"";

    NSRange range82 = NSMakeRange (8, 2);
    NSRange range52 = NSMakeRange (5, 2);
    NSRange range04 = NSMakeRange (0, 4);

    NSString *firstBlock = [inputedDate substringWithRange:range82];
    NSString *secondBlock = [inputedDate substringWithRange:range52];
    NSString *thirdBlock = [inputedDate substringWithRange:range04];

    formattedDate = [formattedDate stringByAppendingString:firstBlock];
    formattedDate = [formattedDate stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    formattedDate = [formattedDate stringByAppendingString:secondBlock];
    formattedDate = [formattedDate stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    formattedDate = [formattedDate stringByAppendingString:thirdBlock];

    return formattedDate;
}
```

The second problem is that the invoice date is loaded into a a table view that contains a date formatter, and changing this would cause the sorting of the table to be lost.

Using the same principle as my handler, and insisting on passing the 16/10/2011 date causes errors on the table view, like: -[__NSCFString timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x40265f3a0

This is the best code I found so far:

```
if (formatterDate == NULL) {
                        NSLog (@"outprintString '%@' = NULL", dateString);
                        NSString *newDate = [BHDateFormatter bhDateFormat:dateString];
                        if ([newDate isEqualToString:@"16/10/2011"]) {
                            formatterDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:@"2011-10-17"];
                            NSLog(@"formatterDate = %@", formatterDate);
                            NSAlert *alert = [[[NSAlert alloc]init] autorelease];
                            [alert setMessageText:[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"Mountain Lion Bug: I have found a date \"16/10/2011\" in your invoice # %@ issued by %@, I must rename the date in your table view to \"17/10/2011\", the date on the rendered invoice file will be display correctly. I apologize for this, but it is an operating system level bug that has to be fixed by Apple.","A comment here"),invoiceNumber, emitente]];
                            [alert runModal];
                        }
                    }
```

Could you please comment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you're right -- that is a bug, and you should report it.  Interestingly, if you set the timezone to Nuuk-Greenland, which is in the same timezone as Rio, it works properly. Also, "2011-10-15" and "2011-10-17" work ok with the Rio time zone, but not "2011-10-16" which is really strange.

This is the simplified the code that I used to test this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSArray *unformattedDatesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"2011-09-18",@"2011-10-16",@"2011-11-13",@"2011-12-11",@"2012-01-08",@"2012-02-05", nil];

    NSDateFormatter *originalFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [originalFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // hh:mm:ss
    NSDateFormatter *newFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [newFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // hh:mm:ss

    for (NSString * aString in unformattedDatesArray) {
        NSString *formattedDate = [newFormat stringFromDate:[originalFormat dateFromString:aString]];
        NSLog(@"Original date string is: %@  formatted date as string is: %@",aString, formattedDate);
    }
}
```

Added Information:

To find the source of this problem, I looped through all the dates in 2011 with the following code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSDateFormatter *originalFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [originalFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // hh:mm:ss
    NSDateFormatter *newFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [newFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]; // hh:mm:ss

    NSDate *start = [originalFormat dateFromString:@"2011-01-01"];
    NSDate *newDate;
    for (int i=0; i<365; i++) {
        newDate = [start dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400 * i];
        NSString *formattedDate = [newFormat stringFromDate:newDate];
        NSLog(@"formatted date as string is: %@",formattedDate);
    }
}
```

When you look at the date strings, you find that there are 2 february 19th's and no October 16th, which is why you get null for that date (although if you log the date objects themselves, you get all the dates correctly).

Comment: +1 yeah, it looks like there's a problem in the underlying `zoneinfo` file regarding `America/Sao_Paulo`.  Please file a bug about this:  https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Dear Rick, Thanks for replying. What do you think is safe for me to do with my code meanwhile? 1) write my own formatting handler? 2) insert and error string in the output string if formatting fails? 3) any other ideas?

Comment: It's not a bug. October 16 is the day that Brazil went onto southern-hemisphere daylight saving time, and your proposed time is during the missing hour. Similarly, February 19th is the day they went off daylight saving time, so the hour is repeated.

Comment: @DaveDeLong It's not a bug. There is a subtlety added by the fact that not all parts of Brazil went onto daylight saving time that year, but since some parts did, the system makes a reasonable assumption about Rio.

Comment: By not including the time you are implicitly including the time. There are some good WWDC videos from last year about calendrical calculation. I believe the advice was don't use midnight, use midday and do it explicitly. Otherwise you set yourself up for the pitfalls of this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. October 16 is the day that Brazil went onto southern-hemisphere daylight saving time that year, and your proposed time (assumed to be midnight, since you don't give an explicit time) is during the missing hour. It is a non-existent time.

Comment: Yes. NSDate includes time. If you ignore it then you are implicitly using midnight and the problem is that there are sometimes two and sometimes no midnight.  See the WWDC videos from 2013.