# A bug? NSDateFormatter dateFromString Returns null only for this date string

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

```
NSString *string = @"1990-04-15";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
return [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

this always return null,it functions ok when "string" changed by any other date string,is this date(1990-04-15) so special?

xcode 5 , IOS 7, iphone app

the whole method and context:

in "Tools.m":

```
+(NSDate *)stringToDate:(NSString *)string{
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
return [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
}
```

and the method called:

```
NSDate *date = [Tools stringToDate:@"1990-04-15"];
NSLog(@"---- the date:%@",date);
```

Comment: Of course this is a special date... Emma Watson was born on it.

Comment: Close voter:  What "minimal information" is absent?

Comment: The code is fine and returns a `NSDate` object when I tested it. Could there be something else which might cause issue?

Comment: Could you show the context of where you are finding this is being returned as nil. This code looks fine so I'm guessing the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is that you have not actually presented the code you're using.

Comment: So you are saying that if you change your string to `1990-04-14`, it works fine?

Comment: What we do not see is the method declaration and the declared return type.

Comment: Can you please post the whole method? And scope where it is used? Because everything is ok with current snippet

Comment: To all those saying it works fine: please include your geographical location and time zone of where it works fine. Also, OP, please include *your* location and time zone as well. I have seen bugs in `NSDateFormatter` that only affect people in a certain area: what "works fine" for one person returns `nil` for another. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167829/nsdateformatter-puzzle-is-this-is-new-mountain-lion-bug for an example of this.

Comment: What's your time zone, locale, and calendar? Does it happen in iOS simulator or Mac using those settings?

Comment: thank NSGod,follow your clue,I solved the problem by adding "    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
",there's an other example:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8442706/nsdateformatter-and-time-zone-issue
I'm in China,and it happens both in simulator and real iPhone.

Comment: @NSGod It's not a bug! The date formatter knows more than you do. :) It has to do with local daylight savings time (in the locale specified or assumed) - the datetime being proposed is during the "missing hour" caused by setting the clock ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you in China? If so, it is because there was a time shift to daylight saving time, so midnight April 15 1990 didn't exist - the time jumped directly to 1:00 AM. (You are not providing a time, and the default time is midnight. And you are not providing a time zone, so your own locale is assumed.)

Comment: The answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167829/nsdateformatter-puzzle-is-this-is-new-mountain-lion-bug is exactly the same: he's in Brazil, and the day that gives trouble is the day Brazil went on daylight saving time that year.

Comment: you are genius!!! I googled a while ,China began to put daylight saving time  into practice exactly that day(April 15 1990 ... Emma Watson was born:)) and stopped it one year later.