NSDateFormatter returns nil for date string from server
I received a date string and a timezone from a web service and I am needing to convert into an NSDate. When setting the format and timezone, I get nil:
NSString *timeZoneString = @"Europe/Paris";
NSString *dateString = @"2024-03-31T02:40:21.000";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'.'SS"];

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:timeZoneString];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:timeZone];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];// return nil

Is there a reason why this specific date string, and using Europe/Paris returns nil when trying to create my date?

Unrelated but all single quotes except the ones around the T are redundant.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839955/341994

There was no 2:40 in the morning on the 31st of March in Paris - Daylight savings/summer time started at 02:00 on the 31st of March, meaning the clocks jumped forward to 03:00 at that time.
nil is the correct result

Thank you! In this case, should I still use NSISO8601DateFormatter has you previously suggested? It strips the time, which is what I would want here.

I would always suggest using NSISO8601DateFormatter when dealing with things that look like ISO8601 - It is simpler than having to define a custom format.

@Paulw11: 31st of March
